# How to remove n-th html element in a string in PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I have a massive table with 5 columns and I need to remove 4th and 5th.

Example:

```
<td><a href="http://sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81belov%C3%A1" title="Ábelová">Ábelová</a></td>
<td><a href="http://sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okres_Lu%C4%8Denec" title="Okres Lučenec">Lučenec</a></td>
<td><a href="http://sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banskobystrick%C3%BD_kraj" title="Banskobystrický kraj">Banskobystrický kraj</a></td>
<td></td>
<td>Ábelfalva</td>
```

to this:

```
<td><a href="http://sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81belov%C3%A1" title="Ábelová">Ábelová</a></td>
<td><a href="http://sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okres_Lu%C4%8Denec" title="Okres Lučenec">Lučenec</a></td>
<td><a href="http://sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banskobystrick%C3%BD_kraj" title="Banskobystrický kraj">Banskobystrický kraj</a></td>
```

in every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PHP's `DOM` extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or any of the DOM parsers suggested in

- [Best methods to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

and use an XPath like

```
/html/body/drill/down/to/your/table/tr/td[position() = 4 or position() = 5]
```

How to remove nodes from a `DOMDocument` has been answered countless times before. See some of [my previous answers on how to do that with DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+DOM+remove) or use the [search function](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DOM+remove+%5Bphp%5D) please.

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace can be a solution, you can also load your file into an SimpleXML object then use a simple loop with a counter and display all td in the tr that aren't 4th nor 5th.
You can also use preg_split, but that would be hard.
So SimpleXML is the best way IMO. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Use [preg_replace](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with pattern that match `td` without `a` in it and replace with empty string. Or [DOM](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) extension.

Comment: I didn't downvote you answer, but I'll give you a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege

Comment: @andre matos: The content of the HTML seems to be well-defined in this case, so I don't think it's necessarily too hard to do this with a regex.

Comment: @andre matos: I was referring to concrete code - for that code preg_replace will work fine. But thanks for link :)

Comment: your solution would be also right, if i were able to create such a regex :D

Answer (score -1):

You can indeed use preg_replace, but I'd suggest a regex that matches the 4. and 5. <td>.*</td> substrings. A less elegant (but simpler, if you don't know regex) solution is using [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) multiple times, using the result of one as the offset of the next.

Comment: i'm lame in regex, can you please show an example how to do it ?